# How to handle an invalid/garbage value while trying to use popen function that returns a permission denied

Tags: c, gdb, file-permissions, popen

I'm trying to write a program that will look for files owned by user. Then print the output into a variable to manipulate it or comunicate it with some other program. The problem is when I put the directory as `/` , most of the early find will be permission denied. But there seems to be a NULL/garbage or something assigned to the variable even though it states that permission denied. Here are the codes:

```
static struct{
          char file_owned[8192][1024];
}information;

void get_file_owned(char *username)
{
  FILE *stream3;
  extern FILE *popen();
  char command[1024];
  char buff[1024];
  int i;

  sprintf(command, "find / -user %s -ls",username);
  if(!(stream3 = popen(command), "r"))){
       exit(1);
  }
  i=0;
  while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stream3)!=NULL){
       sprintf(information.file_owned[i],"%s",buff); //it print something into file_owned. But I do now know what. 
       i++;
  }
  pclose(stream3);
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  static char *username;
  int i;

  username = "fikrie";
  get_file_owned(username);

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%s\n",information.process_owned[i]);
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

This is the output:

```
find: `/proc/1657/task/1659/ns` : Permission denied
find: `/proc/1713/task/1713/ns` : Permission denied
...
...
//There's a lot of this kind of output
...
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

I'm expecting its caused by the permission denied. Which will then just print a garbage into process_owned. How should I handle output for the permission denied? I've tried to handle a NULL inside the get_file_owned function. But it doesn't solve it.

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stream3)!=NULL){
    if(buff == NULL){
    continue;
    }
    sprintf(information.file_owned[i],"%s",buff);
    i++;
}
```

I've also tried to use gdb to see about the segmentation fault. This is the result:

```
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 _IO_getline info (fp=0x9ec50b8, buf=0x2 <Address 0x2 out of bounds>, n=254, delim=10, extract_delim=1, eof=0x0) at iogetline.c:91
iogetline.c: No such file or directory.
```

Please take note that if I tried to run this in my home directory. `/home/fikrie/Documents`. There's no segmentation fault or error.

**EDIT:**
I have also run this program as root. Change the structure way into this type:

```
struct{
   char file_owned[1024];
}information[1024];   //I tried changing this into 8094 also. Just in case the array for this struct is not enough.
```

Comment: ahahaha..that's just an example. Just lazy to type everything. But I hope that helps to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: did you try running your program as root user??

Comment: @const Yes.I have tried using the root user as well. It still display segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

`find` propably returns more then 8192 lines. Therefore the while loop overflows the array `file_owned`.

Comment: yes. Seems so because its assigning something to the struct eventhough theres a Permission denied. Is there a way for me to not assign anything or skip the sprintf if the file is Permission denied.